# Consuming API with graphql queries throwing 401 error on R but working fine on Python

Tags: python, r, rest, graphql, http-status-code-401

I have a requirement to access some information through an API. I need to do this on R. I tried doing on Python and it worked just fine but facing 401 error while doing the same operation on R.

I have the API key and also know the query to be performed. I have attached both Python and R code below.

Python:

```
import requests

headers = {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'Authorization': 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX',
}

query = """
{
    boards (ids: 157244624) {
        permissions
    }
}
"""

response = requests.get('https://XYZwebsite.com/', headers=headers, json={'query': query})
```

R:

```
require(httr)

headers = c(
  `Content-Type` = 'application/json',
  `Authorization` = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'
)

data = '{
    boards (ids: 157244624) {
        permissions
    }
}'

res <- GET(url = 'https://XYZwebsite.com/', add_headers(.headers=headers), body = data)
```

Am i missing out something in the R code? It looks pretty much the same but i am getting a 401 error on R for some weird reason.

Answer (score 1):

In my case api key was expired... really long journey let me to:

1. amplify update api
2. walk through all
3. choose api key
4. enter new api key name
5. enter 365 days no further changes
6. amplify push will not detect changes, so use amplify push --force
   maybe it helps

Comment: btw i never thought that the input of stackoverflow could be so difficult as an editor

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps try:

```
r <- GET("https://XYZwebsite.com/", 
         add_headers(`Content-Type` = "application/json",
                     `Authorization` = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"),
         body = data)
```

Edit:
With the [gist](https://gist.github.com/rentrop/83cb1d8fc8593726a808032e55314019) you are working off of:

Authenticate first:

```
token <- GQL(auth_query)$authenticate$jwtToken
```

Then you can run your queries by passing the token you get in the response:

```
GQL(current_person_query, .token = token)
```

Seems like you are trying to do two things at once.

If you already have the token then it looks like you are passing it incorrectly:

```
auth_header <- paste("bearer", .token)
res <- POST(.url, body = pbody, encode="json", add_headers(Authorization=auth_header), ...)
```

As it should be passed as "bearer XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX".

Comment: I would guess that the "data" portion isn't formatted correctly.

Comment: `url <- "http://httpbin.org/post"
body <- list(a = 1, b = 2, c = 3)

# Form encoded
r <- POST(url, body = body, encode = "form")`

Comment: in [the docs](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/httr/vignettes/quickstart.html) the body is a list, not a character string. (At least, for a POST request).

Comment: Yes that's right. But my data is in the form of GraphQL query. I referred to (https://gist.github.com/rentrop/83cb1d8fc8593726a808032e55314019) this github document and turns out we can use the GraphQl query itself in the data section. Please have a look and let me know what you think.

Comment: I thought that your code was actually attempting to authenticate, but glancing at that it looks like your are getting a 401 (Unauthorized error) because you have to authenticate before you run queries. see the update.

Comment: I didn't understand what you mean by authenticate before running queries. Could you please elaborate.

Comment: If you are talking about the username and password authentication, it is already done and the api key that is generated is after logging in.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I forgot to mention that i have already tried the same code that is there in the document i shared. It still gives me the same error.